# Export FBX or OBJ one click script As well import FBX or OBJ one click

Tags: python, scripting, import, .fbx, obj

Looking for simple script as mentioned in title "Blender Export Script FBX or OBJ one click script As well import FBX or OBJ one click"
as via Google I did not receive any positive answers.
Maybe someone already wrote such code?
If not it will be great if someone can help me to reach this goal.
As with all my previous software which I was using I had such script from zbrush to maya etc..
However in Blender I did not find any.

```
from pathlib import Path
import bpy

folder = Path(r"C:\Asset_temp")
fbx_files = [f for f in folder.glob("**/*.fbx") if f.is_file()]
for fbx_file in fbx_files:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=str(fbx_file))
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        obj.name = fbx_file.stem
```

Comment: What's wrong with using Blender's File > Import and Export menu?

Comment: I even don't know how to explain, simple is it not efficient . If you not working in 3D field, then there is no problem. you can work on singular item. However i don't have such luxury.

Comment: Well both the Fbx and (legacy) Obj importers and exporters in Blender are addons written in Python and of course are open source, so you could always have a rummage round in the source files in Blender.